# Bacula v5.0.2 Windows Installation Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, bacula

First off, I am very new to Bacula but I'm very intriqued from what I've read. I'm looking to set up Bacula 5.0.2 on a Windows 2008 R2 server. I've run the installer and at the end it asks me to configure DIR name, DIR password, DIR Address. Windows documentation is somewhat hard to come by and I'm not certain what exactly I'm supposed to enter here. Do I need to create a local account that matches this info? Will the installation process create the account for me? Will this be the account that handles the FD daemon/service? I'm also not certain if Address means network location or local direcory. I apologize for my ignorance.

Currently I'm trying to use the following information:
Name: john
pass: john
address: thin1 (server name although I have also tried thin1.fqdm.local and 10.0.0.104)

This info allows for the installer to complete successfully. However, when I run the BAT it hangs at, "Connecting to Director thin1:9101". The Bacula File Service is currently running under the local system account. What am I doing wrong? What do I have yet to do?

Once I get this working properly I assume I will need to install clients on all my Windows boxes?

Also, this is a 64-bit cpu but I am installing the 32-bit client. Are there any issues with this? Should I be using the 32-bit client?

Thanks very much for the help.

Edit 1:
Is the issue I'm running into because the director MUST be running on a linux box? There is no Windows port of the director? Can Bacula exist in a 100% Windows environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bacula documentation](http://www.bacula.org/5.0.x-manuals/en/main/main/Windows_Version_Bacula.html) mentions that the File Daemon is the only component of production-quality on Windows. I don't know how you managed to install a Director on a Windows box, but this is definitely not something that's supposed to work reliably.

For the record, I run the Bacula Director and Storage Daemon on a Linux box, with 5 Linux boxes and 4 Windows boxes as clients (File Daemons). The Windows version of the File Daemon has always worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem is that the physical machine (the one with the SAS HBA) is running Windows 2008 R2. At first I wanted to virtualize my director but hyper-v doesn't allow you to attach/map SCSI ports directly to devices, with the exception of phyisical disk (pass-though). It looks as though I'm going to have to build a new server to handle this operation. In you opinion is Bacula demanding in terms of hardware?

Comment: I don't think that Bacula is very demanding by itself, however running multiple jobs at the same time may tax the network or the backup volumes. My Bacula server is an Intel Atom 230 with 2GB RAM running CentOS 5.5 and running 4 simultaneous jobs has no noticeable effect on the box responsiveness (sorry I don't have any precise number there).